# Merge objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have for example:

```
$onePack = $pack->findByCity('London'); //this return me 3 objects from class Pack
$twoPack = $pack->findByCity('New York'); //this return me 2 objects from class Pack
$threePack = $pack->findByCity('Los Angeles'); //this return me 5 objects from class Pack
```

And I would like merge this object to one variable and next use with  foreach.

I know - i can make array, for example:

```
$array = array();
```

and next:

```
foreach($onePack as $one) {
    $array[] = $one;
}
foreach($twoPack as $two) {
    $array[] = $two;
}
foreach($threePack as $three) {
    $array[] = $three;
}
```

And now I have all objects (10) in one variable, but maybe is better way for this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$cities = array('London', 'New York', 'Los Angeles');

$arr = array();
foreach($cities as $city) {
  $arr[] = $pack->findByCity($city); 
}
```

You can add new cities to the cities array and they will all be added to the $arr variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge

```
$arr = array_merge($pack1->toArray(), $pack2->toArray(), $pack3->toArray());
```

And create an toArray method in the pack object.